# Default position of Documents, Music and Pictures under Firefox in Ubuntu WSL

Tags: filesystem, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and through it, Ubuntu:

`wsl --install Ubuntu`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

There is one automatic configurations of the files for documents and images that strikes me as odd, and different from what I think I recall seeing on a Linux machine.

The issue is that instead of being in the main user directory they are under `~/snap/firefox/common` as in here:

[image]

Is this the expected placement of these folders? If it isn't how can I correct it?

Comment: Unable to reproduce in a test environment. A stock install of Firefox on Ubuntu Desktop 23.04 (non-WSL) does not have `~/snap/firefox/common`

Comment: Maybe ask Microsoft Support?

Comment: @Marco This is *likely* much more an Ubuntu question than it is about WSL.  The Ubuntu distribution for WSL is based off Ubuntu Server, which doesn't create these directories by default (to my knowledge) even when not running under WSL.

Comment: Antoni - I'm assuming that you've installed WSL/Ubuntu, enabled Systemd, and installed Firefox using Snap.  Is there anything else you can think about that you might have configured?  I'm working on trying this out myself to see if I can find a way to reproduce, but any additional details might be helpful - Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds My apologies for not being fluent in some of these aspects. I did install Firefox with `sudo apt install firefox`. The rest of the packages either came with Ubuntu, or got downloaded and compiled with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`. At this point I have just moved the Documents, Movies, Pictures and such from under Firefox to the home directory, and nothing was disrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this behavior on WSL, and yes, it's "expected" to some degree.  As I mentioned in the comments, this is probably the same behavior we'd see in Ubuntu Server, where there's no desktop environment by default.

The XDG directories such as `Downloads`, `Documents`, `Music`, etc. are typically created by the Desktop Manager (or perhaps, more technically, the Session Manager) during the user's initial login to that desktop.  As far as I can tell, this is done by running `xdg-user-dirs-update` during the session setup.

Since in WSL, we're running Firefox in a GUI *without* a desktop environment, that step never gets done.  This would be similar, under Ubuntu Server, to running Firefox through XRDP or even X forwarding to another system.

While I understand from the comments that you've already solved the issue by simply moving the directories, for future readers, you should probably do a one-time run of:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update
```

... before running Firefox or other apps which adhere to the XDG standard for the first time.

Because Firefox isn't finding the directories in the expected location, it seems to have created them in its "user" directory as a Snap.

If you delete those directories, run `xdg-user-dirs-update`, and run Firefox again, it will not recreate the directories under `~/snap/firefox/common`.  That directory itself will exist, but it will be empty, and the "normal" locations for `Documents`, etc. will be used.